# Athena Creating Table from JSON, how to deal with multiple nested structure

Tags: json, amazon-athena

I am trying to create a table from a json, the json being like

```
{"ocNo" : "6090","clientSessionKey" : {"office" : {"ortsCode" : 6090},"workstationNo" : 1}}
```

I tried to achieve it by executing following query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE events_tryout(
  ocNo string,
  clientSessionKey struct<office struct<ortsCode: int>,
  workstationNo int> 
  ) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://lab.ea38-zplus.cap.nonprod.int2/test/'
```

However I get the following error message:
`FAILED: ParseException line 1:81 missing : at 'struct' near '<EOF>' line 1:118 missing : at 'int' near '<EOF>'`
I checked that the json is valid, so that is not the problem.
However, when I run it by removing ClientSessionKey and this nesting it works, which tells me, that the problem is adding another nesting. Can Athena deal with structs inside structs while creating tables from json, or should another approach be taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is a missing `:` after `office`, just like the error message is saying.

There is also another `:` missing after `workstationNo`.

Try `struct<office:struct<ortsCode:int>,workstationNo: int>`.